# GitHub - Pulling the master on branch, and pushing the change is merging the branch to master

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I have pulled `master` branch on GitHub and it's up to date.

Steps which I followed later:

1. Pulled a branch `branch1` using command `git pull remote branch1`
2. Pulled `master` again using `git pull origin master`
3. Changed a file ( on `master` )
4. `git add filename.txt`
5. `git commit -m "committing filename.txt"`
6. `git push`

But when I pushed it merged `branch1` to the `master`. How did this happen? As I had pulled `master` again, I was expecting `branch1` to be overwritten.

What did I miss here?

Comment: A pull merges the remote branch into your local branch. So if those two diverged, you get a merge commit.

Comment: Please start up `gitk --all` to get a visual impression of the branches. You might want to include a screenshot here.

Comment: I got my mistake. Git Pull is nothing but git fetch and git merge. Hence the issue. Thanks for your inputs